# Capistrano tasks running principle?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

As the question ask at last year by other people:
"I have a transaction consisting of 8 tasks. I want to run the transaction on 10 servers, one server at a time. Using :max_hosts => 1, restricts each task to one server at a time, but then runs the same task on the next server. I want to run all tasks on a single server before moving on. Is there a best practice for this scenario ?

Thanks"

I have the same problem, can somebody help us?